# How to uninstall nVidia Graphics Adapter WDDM1.1 optional update?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Windows 7 Home on notebook. I installed optional update for nVidia (Graphics Adapter WDDM1.1, Graphics Adapter WDDM1.2, Graphics Adapter WDDM1.3, Other hardware - NVIDIA GeForce 9300M GS). Although everything is working normally and I dont have errors, I noticed that this update mainly intended for improving gaming performance, and has installed a varios extra stuff, nVidia 3D Vision Driver, Graphic Driver 327.02, Update 1.14.17 
As I don't use my laptop for gaming, I don't really need this update. How to unistall this update properly, all it components and registry entries? Also, I think driver update removed the previous drivers during the installation process.

Comment: remove it with the help of the control panel->installed programs.

Comment: Well, this is an obvious way. Will it remove all traces of the driver, include registry entries? How then to install default graphic driver?

Comment: this should remove all parts. You can extract the Exe and use the device manager to only update the GPU driver.

Comment: should I do system restore in addition after uninstalling driver to roll back Windows state?

Comment: no, there is not need for that.

Comment: After uninstalling NVIDIA driver and software, Windows automatically installed some generic nVidia driver. Next time when Windows checked for updates, it prompted to install "important" update _"NVIDIA driver update for NVIDIA GeForce 9300M GS"_. I installed, but it was the **same** as optional update I just uninstalled: _"nVidia Graphic Adapter WDDM1.1, Graphic Adapter WDDM1.2,Graphic Adapter WDDM1.3, Other hardware- NVIDIA GeForce 9300M GS"_, the same bloatware 580MB..

Comment: disable the automatic installation of Update and hide the nVIDIA driver update on Windows Update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to remove the nVidia - Graphics adapter WDDM1.1, Graphics Adapter WDDM1.2, Graphics Adapter WDDM1.3 :

1. Search "Device Manager" in your desktop.
2. Double click on Display Adapters.
3. Then double click on your graphic adapter. You will see your Graphic card properties window.
4. Click on Driver
5. Then click on "Roll Back Driver". This will take you to the previous non-updated version of driver.